# How to get unbiased parameters for a regression with asymmetric and non-zero disturbances?

Tags: regression, error, unbiased-estimator

Very generally, we have a multiple regression model where the disturbances have distributions that are both asymmetric and generally don't have a conditional mean of 0.

$y=XB + \gamma\,,$

where

$E[\gamma|X] = \theta$ with, for example, $\theta > 0$

How do we get unbiased estimates for such a model? I know that we can reparameterize this model by subtracting and adding $\theta$.

Additionally, I know that slope estimates are unbiased, but what I'm unable to do is how to get an unbiased estimate of the original model intercept. Taking the simple case:

$y=\alpha + X\beta + \gamma$ where $E[\gamma|X] = \theta$

What is an unbiased estimate of $\alpha$? Is it simply $\alpha_{ols} + \theta$?

Comment: What's $E(\hat{\alpha}_{_{OLS}})$ going to be equal to?

Comment: If $y=(\alpha + \theta) + X\beta + (\gamma - \theta)$ is the repameterized model, then $y=\alpha* + X\beta + \gamma*$ can be estimated by OLS. $E[\hat{a*_{ols}}] = \bar{y} - b\bar{x}$, as usual. Since $\alpha* = \alpha + \theta, then E[\hat{a_{ols}}] = a*_{ols} + \theta$.

Comment: So if you know  $E(\hat{\alpha}_{_{OLS}})=\alpha+\theta$ what's $E(\hat{\alpha}_{_{OLS}}+\theta)$?

Answer (score 0):

You say in comments

> If $y=(\alpha + \theta) + X\beta + (\gamma - \theta)$ is the repameterized model, then $y=\alpha* + X\beta + \gamma*$ can be estimated by OLS. $E[\hat{a*_{ols}}] = \bar{y} - b\bar{x}$, as usual. Since $\alpha* = \alpha + \theta, then E[\hat{a_{ols}}] = a*_{ols} + \theta$.

I assume this implies you realize that $E(\hat{\alpha}_{_{OLS}})=\alpha+\theta$

Consequently $E(\hat{\alpha}_{_{OLS}}+\theta) = \alpha+\theta+\theta$.

That's ... probably not what you want to do. Assuming $\theta$ is known, ... I bet you can figure out what to do instead of adding $\theta$ to the estimated intercept.